# Honda Odyssey 2003 makes squeaking noises on cold start

Tags: engine, honda, belt

Something squeaks when I start the engine after the car was sitting in garage for the night. Squeaking goes away after 2-3 minutes. [Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dMjzkGTm09U)

Car has following replaced a month ago:

- [harmonic balancer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004SEXKE2) (crankshaft)
- both power steering and serpentine belts (don't know brand, bought @Autozone).

Power steering pump was replaced 1 year ago with [A1 Cardone brand](http://www.autopartswarehouse.com/sku/A1_Cardone/Power_Steering_Pump/A1215268.html), power steering fluid reservour is full, no leaks.

This might be a duplicate of [this](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/615/cold-start-squeaking-noise-in-engine) and [this](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/2669/squeaking-noise-when-cold-start-suspect-something-wrong-with-belts-also-engine) posts. They indicate a belt tension/worn out problems. I do not believe that the tension is a problem here, the belts seem to sit pretty tight, and they are new, as I already mentioned. Maybe I need to spray them with some sort of belt conditioner or something?..

Considering the replaced parts, what else is likely to cause the squeaks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the belt tensioner. Note that the bearing can make noise while it is still performing correctly, maintaining tension on the belt. So the fact that the belt is new and that has proper tension does not exclude the possibility that the tensioner bearing is noisy.

I should add that while the tensioner functions now, if it is making noise, it could fail at some point in the future. Possibly even the near future, as [this person](http://www.automotiveforums.com/t1067597-discuss97_riv__belt_tensioner_pulley_noisy.html) discovered. (If that link disappears, the person asked a similar question on July 10th, and on July 30th posted a followup to report that the tensioner failed while driving, throwing off the belt.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the nights dew could play a part by dampening the metal and allowing for slippage of the belt causing it to squeal momentarily until the dew dries up. The problem could be as simple as tightening your alternator belt. There is an adjustment bolt that allows you to loosen or tighten your alternator belt. A couple of turns should do it. You may also want to look into your Idler Tension Pulley.  Maybe the bearing is going bad.